# ¿Cómo eliminar un evento en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Hola qué tal amigos aún soy nuevo en el lenguaje de JavaScript, sin embargo tengo un problema el cual he intentado solucionar y nomas no doy, no encuentro la solución. Tengo un evento en un botón el cual al presionarlo muestra la hora y tengo otro botón que detiene la hora pero al momento de darle clic al botón no pasa nada. Les anexo el código.

```
const $iniciarReloj =  document.getElementById("iniciarReloj"),
      $detenerReloj = document.getElementById("detenerReloj"),
      $iniciarAlarma = document.getElementById("iniciarAlarma"),
      $detenerAlarma = document.getElementById("detenerAlarma");

const $horas = document.querySelector(".horas"),
      $puntero = document.querySelector(".puntero"),
      $minutos = document.querySelector(".minutos"),
      $segundos = document.querySelector(".segundos");


  
  function setTime(){
      //DATOS DE JAVASCRIP
      let date = new Date(),
      hora = date.getHours(),
      minutos = date.getMinutes(),
      segundos = date.getSeconds();
      
      //VERIFICANDO LOS SEGUNDOS Y MINUTOS
      minutos = checTime(minutos);
      segundos = checTime(segundos);
      
      $horas.textContent = hora;
      $minutos.textContent = minutos;
      $segundos.textContent = segundos;
      
      setTimeout(function(){
          setTime();
      },500);
}

function checTime(i){
    if(i<10){
        i="0"+i;
    }
    return i;
}

//BOTON QUE INICIA LA HORA
$iniciarReloj.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    setTime();
});

//BOTON QUE DETIENE LA HORA PERO NO FUNCIONA
$detenerReloj.addEventListener("click",function(){
    $iniciarReloj.removeEventListener("click",setTime);
});
```

Comment: Si abres la consola sale algún error?

Comment: No, no sale ningún error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu caso concreto me parece que has complicado mas de la cuenta el codigo, lo puedes simplificar mucho utilizando un interval en lugar de una funcion recursiva.

```
const $iniciarReloj = document.getElementById('iniciarReloj');
const $detenerReloj = document.getElementById('detenerReloj');
const $iniciarAlarma = document.getElementById('iniciarAlarma');
const $detenerAlarma = document.getElementById('detenerAlarma');

const $horas = document.querySelector('.horas');
const $puntero = document.querySelector('.puntero');
const $minutos = document.querySelector('.minutos');
const $segundos = document.querySelector('.segundos');
let interval;

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        return `0${i}`;
    }
    return i;
}

function setTime() {
    // DATOS DE JAVASCRIP
    const date = new Date();
    const hora = date.getHours();
    let minutos = date.getMinutes();
    let segundos = date.getSeconds();

    // VERIFICANDO LOS SEGUNDOS Y MINUTOS
    minutos = checkTime(minutos);
    segundos = checkTime(segundos);

    $horas.textContent = hora;
    $minutos.textContent = minutos;
    $segundos.textContent = segundos;
}


// BOTON QUE INICIA LA HORA
$iniciarReloj.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // En caso de que exista ya un interval limpiarlo antes de crear uno nuevo para evitar que se duplique
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    // Crear el intervalo que ejecutara setTime cada 1000 ms y almacenar el id en la variable interval
    interval = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
});

// BOTON QUE DETIENE LA HORA PERO NO FUNCIONA
$detenerReloj.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, con lo que me pusiste pude hacer de nuevo esa parte de limpiar el intervalo, agregue el evento al document y cada que detecte el click pues se inicializa el interval, en caso contrario limpio el interval y todo funciona correctamente, de nuevo muchas gracias.